# repeat skobbler maps horizontally with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm trying to get skobbler maps to repeat horizontally
if you load this page
http://developer.skobbler.com/demo/skobbler-tiles-openlayers.html
and zoom out, the map will not repeat horizontally

However if you use this link and zoom out
http://developer.skobbler.com/web-tiles/embedded
it works as I want (i.e. it repeats across the screen)

However, I'm using OpenLayers and not an Iframe

Is what I want to do possible with OpenLayers?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made some minor changes to your code. In fact I've added a few properties to your layer:

```
var skoLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("skobbler",
                ["${z}/${x}/${y}.png?api_key=<Your Key Here>"], 
                    {numZoomLevels: 18, 
                    sphericalMercator: true, 
                    isBaseLayer: true, 
                    wrapDateLine: true, 
                    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -180, 180, 120),
                    attribution: attrib
                });
```

Some explanations:

- `wrapDateLine` repeats the maps horizontally *but only if*
- the layer `isBaseLayer`
- the `120` value in the `maxExtent` is not choosed arbitrary, but for centering the map, focusing like in your example. It seems that using `wrapDateLine: true` overrides `setCenter`. If you need another center you must to adjust all the values by attempts.

And **[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13060205/Stackexchange/Skobbler/skobbler.zip)**'s the whole code for you, to easily test it. Just unzip the archive (*tested for  viruses*), extract the *scrobbler.html* file and double click it.

Just zoom out and move the map, as you like.